# How to use slot-scope for index in for loop?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm using [vue-datatable](https://vuejs-datatable.patrickstephan.me/usage/custom-templates) which has the following:

```
<slot v-for="(row, i) in processed_rows" :row="row" :columns="normalized_columns">
```

And I'm trying to get the index like this:

```
<template slot-scope="{ row, i }">
```

However, `i` always returns as `undefined`.